# How to get timestamp of a picture?

Tags: python, image, photo, exif

I know `EXIF` data is enough to know the date and time of which a photo is taken. But nowadays editing `EXIF` data is a simple task. Is there any other reliable method to get the `timestamp` of a picture taken?

Comment: The theory of analysing image data is not a good topic for SO unless it is related to actual code.

Comment: timestamp from image text or file property ??

Comment: Question is not regarding image processing. I meant timestamp from file property @VivekAnanthan